# How to enable/disable cellular data on win 10 once configured?

Tags: windows-10

On Windows 10, once configured and working, how can I disable and reenable cellular data usage? I see several ways to do so for Wi-Fi.
Thanks!

Side note: since I use a German system, I'd love to get the navigation path rather than just the name of the option.

Comment: Do you mean Settings  > Network & Internet  > Cellular  > Let Windows manage this connection ?

Comment: Sounds about right, but that option doesn't appear for me. Might be a driver issue - in update the question with details asap.